# What does it mean for transparent background?

Tags: image, image-processing

For an image with transparent background, what's the back ground color? 0,0,0? or 255, 255, 255 in RGB? or any value is fine only if alpha value is 255?

Comment: isn't the alpha 0 for transparent?

Comment: 0,0,0 will set to background color to WHITE... TRANSPARENT is not a color, that is what you need to code...

Comment: any tool to show pixel color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background color doesn't matter, as long as the alpha value is 0 (not 255).

Comment: What language/platform are you using?